# Why do i have to call npm link as administrator?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I installed some nodejs packages globally via

```
sudo npm install gulp -g
```

Now I (or another developer on the same machine) wants to use it in a project with

```
me@host:/my/project$ npm link gulp
```

It fails with

```
unbuild gulp@3.8.11
npm ERR! Error: EPERM, chmod '/my/projectnode_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, chmod '/my/projectnode_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js']
npm ERR!   errno: 50,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   path: '/my/projectnode_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "link" "gulp"
npm ERR! cwd /raid5/workspaces/jgr/aktivglueck-laravel
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! path /my/projectnode_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno 50
npm ERR! stack Error: EPERM, chmod '/my/projectnode_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /my/projectnpm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

With

```
sudo npm link gulp
```

everything works fine.

What I want to know is: **Why does `npm link` need admin permissions?** In my understanding I am creating a link inside my project folder where I have full permissions - so what does it do on the global system?

Comment: Okay, I could just avoid the global install and use `npm install` in the project (I have a `packages.json`) ...

Comment: Did you find out how to use `npm link`? I have the same issue when using `gulp` in a Docker container, and I don't like the concept of installing `gulp` twice.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `npm link` creates a symlink to the current directory in wherever your globally installed node packages are. See [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link).

If you don't have write rights to that path (you can check with `npm config get prefix`) you'll get the error you see there.

To avoid having to `sudo` global installs/links, you could change the ownership/rights of that directory.

Comment: Common sense told me, that the link would be from *my project* to *the global installed packages* .. Strange .. Thanks :-)